# how to use c# variables in sql commands

Tags: c#, sql, variables

This is what I want to use;

```
string insertQuery = @"insert into userinfo (UserName, FirstName, LastName, 
                      E-mail, Password,  Country) 
                      values ( '" + uname + "', '" + fname + 
                      "','" + lname + "', '" + email + "')";
```

where every one of the variables in between the + are string variables with values in them. but when I run this command, I get some incorrect syntax error.

This is the new error i get;

> errorSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary
>   data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   Registration.RegistrationPage.Button1_Click1(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in c:\Users\kristhnen.jagambrum\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Registration\Registration\RegistrationPage.aspx.cs:line
>   50 ClientConnectionId:6d959e49-5b62-43be-b202-76f7eb1fbd2c

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should ***NEVER*** concatenate together your SQL statements like you're proposing; ***ALWAYS*** use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection!!

Comment: You're listing 6 columns to insert data into, but only 4 values. And yes, please look into using `Parameters` to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: In addition to what @marc_s said, the column `E-mail` needs to be escaped since this is an expression, `E` minus `mail`. Try `"E-mail"` or `[E-mail]`, but yes, **do not concatenate strings to form sql!**

Comment: Heed the above warning first & foremost, but in the short term, you can debug the code & see what value is assigned to `insertQuery`

Comment: `I get some incorrect syntax error` is not very useful information, at all. Why not copy and paste the error text into your post?

Comment: What about Password and Country column where is their corresponding values ??

Answer (score 5):

It's very good that you asked - the code that you show is a perfect illustration of two security issues in a single line:

- The table structure is an illustration of what lets hackers steal user passwords.
- The C# code is what makes SQL injection attacks possible.

Fixing the first problem is hard: you need to learn about password hashing and how to store user info in DB. Here is a Q&A that will help: [*Best way to store passwords in DB*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1054022/335858)

The second problem is easier - all you need is replacing the injected values with parameter names, and then adding the values for each parameter name:

```
... // Create SQL command, then set its text
command.CommandTest = @"INSERT INTO userinfo (
    UserName, FirstName, LastName, E-mail, Password_hash, Password_salt, Country
) VALUES ( @uname, @fname, @lname, @email, @pwd_hash, @pwd_salt, @country)";
// Bind the parameters
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uname", uname));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fname", fname));
... // ...and so on
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you don't, because it is a bad idea. You should be using `SQlCommand` instead

[Check This out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx),and there are plenty of examples of how to use it. Appending variables in the way you doing is considered to be the mistake number 3 in the list of [25 most dangerous programming mistakes.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/top-25-most-dangerous-programming-mistakes/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, and not use direct parameter in sql command

```
public const string InsertStmtUsersTable = "insert into userinfo (UserName, FirstName, LastName, 
                      [E-mail], Password,  Country) values (@UserName, @FirstName, @LastName, 
                      @[E-mail], @Password,  @Country) "
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(InsertStmtUsersTable, conn))
        {
           command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

           command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", userNameString));
           command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FirstName", FirstNameString));
           // Rest of your Parameters here

           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. `SqlCommand` is disposable too, wrap it in a `using`.  2. Rather than `Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(...))` you can just use `Parameters.AddWithValue()`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: you should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and be careful using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @JeroenMostert: there are multiple way to do everything, this is just the sample code, so that OP got some idea, how to do this

Comment: @marc_s: thanks for that one, I had it tickling in the back of my mind but couldn't find the page. Note that in this case, the `new SqlParameter()` omits the type, so it's certainly no *better*.

Comment: Thanks  @marc_s, to notice typo, Using of using